# Summer Sea Travel from Dubrovnik to Split

Tags: sea-travel, croatia, dubrovnik, split

During the last week of June, we are planning to travel from Dubrovnik to Split. There are ferries and catamarans listed in guidebooks but I'm having trouble confirming details:

Are there sea transports from Dubrovnik to Split during the last week of June?

On what schedules and how long does the trip take?

Is a stop-over, either for a few hours or over-night, at Korcula possible?

Comment: @pnuts - I assume some of the first page table lists days of the week. Could you please translate as an answer? This seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work at this time... PHP error. Maybe they  haven't seen that part of the site in a while. I'll try again.

Comment: @pnuts - The English version is not working still. Could you please tell me which of the destination listed is Korcula?

Comment: @pnuts - Yes, I included when, from where, to where and how in this question and am baffled about why it is on hold. In the link you sent, I never see korcula appear in the table, although it's listed in the header above, so I can't tell what is the arrival there. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kapetan Luka TP operate a high-speed ferry between Split and Dubrovnik, with various intermediate stops including Korcula.](http://www.krilo.hr/en/sailing_schedule.html) According to the linked website, between the 1st of June and 27th September 2015, the ferries run every day. It would seem there's one ferry that runs a round trip Split - Dubrovnik - Split within the same day. Below is the timetable and the price list, courtesy of [the company website](http://www.krilo.hr/en/sailing_schedule.html) ([here is a pdf version](http://www.krilo.hr/images/Sailing_schedule_DUBROVNIK.pdf)):

[image: Ferry timetable]

For more information you can contact the company at:

```
MB Kapetan Luka TP - High Speed ship Services

Address: Poljička cesta - Krilo 4,
21314 Krilo Jesenice
Telephone: 021 / 645 476
Fax: 021 / 872 877
Web: www.krilo.hr

Contact person 1: Luka Tomić
Email: luka@krilo.hr
Contact person 2: Ivana Tomić
Email: ivana.tomic@krilo.hr
```